# Secure server-side output from a client-side app

Tags: java, security, applet, server-side, data-security

I converted a local application to a Java applet for data security<sup>1</sup> but I cannot figure out how  to output information to a file.  I am inputting files by a URL object but do not know how to output data to a file on the server.

1. **secure** in that the person running the program in supervised conditions cannot keep it and run it for someone else (it is a survey I am piloting).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: *"I converted a local application to a java applet for data security"* Since conversion to an applet does not achieve the goal, that statement makes no sense to me.

Comment: *"do not know how to output data to a file on the server"* The applet cannot do it alone, it must be supported by server side functionality.  E.G. FTP or a servlet that accepts file uploads.

Comment: what i meant by secure is that the person running the program in supervised conditions cannot keep it and run it for someone else (it is a survey i am piloting)

Comment: A [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) deployed desktop app. can provide every bit of security that would be available by an applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets run on the client, not on the server, so an applet can't do this, period. What it *can* do is send data to a service of some kind on your server, which can then turn around and write the data to a file.

Comment: I still think 'applet' is the wrong way to go for this, but.. +1

Comment: Oh, it is *totally* wrong, I agree! Sending the data across the Internet does not make it any more secure!